# django rest get instance of validator field of serializer

Tags: python, django, rest

I need to get the instance of the serializer field validator. I have not found such information on the Internet...

```
If i have a model:
class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = FileField(max_length=200, storage=Storage(), upload_to=get_file_path, validators=FileValidator(max_size=10*1024*1024))

I can get the instance of validator somehow this way
MyModel._meta.get_field('file').validators[0]

I need it for an example to mock max_size attribute in tests
with mock.patch.object(target=Mymodel._meta.get_field('file').validators[0], attribute='max_size, new=1)

Now I have another model for which validation occurs on the serializer

class TextItemFileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     attachments = SomeCustomField(validators=[ArrayMaxLengthValidator(limit_value=30)])

and I need to mock limit_value in the same way as for the model via the validator instance
```

But the problem is that I do not know how to access to the instance of validator.
Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
obj = None   # TextItem Instance
serializer = TextItemFileSerializer(obj)
validators = serializer.get_fields()['attachments'].validators

validators[0]
$ <class 'app.models.UniqueValidator'>]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Everything works. I initially did not believe but tried and earned my great surprise.